# How to delete the choice text on the left of a Slider question in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, slider, uislider, qualtrics

This might be a bit of a newbie question, but here I am.

I want to have a Slider question in qualtrics, but without the choice text to the left of the slider. To be clearer:

[image]

I want the "Click to write Choice 1" part to disappear altogether, but if I delete the text also the slider goes missing and I am left with just the labels and the values. I basically want the question to be in the text above and then the person just gets the line where she/can drag the thing to answer, where no additional text is displayed to the left of the slider bar.

An example here:

[image]

How it can be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Mobile Friendly" box in the question options.  It will only show when you preview/view the question.  It will still appear to the left in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an empty space or write `&nbsp;` in the text field.